# How to get property name from expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have class Test:

```
class Test
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And function Exec which accepts expression:

```
void Exec<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
}

...
Exec<Test>(t => t.Id);
```

How can I get the property name used in expression? In the code above this should be Id.

Comment: Duplicate of [Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something like:

```
private static string GetMemberName(Expression expression)
{
    switch(expression.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            return ((MemberExpression)expression).Member.Name;
        case ExpressionType.Convert:
            return GetMemberName(((UnaryExpression)expression).Operand);
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException(expression.NodeType.ToString());
    }
}
```

with:

```
public void Exec<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    string name = GetMemberName(expression.Body);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but in my case, I always got exception InvalidCastException. "Can't cast System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression to type System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression"

Comment: @Alexander added support for `Convert` expressions